# shadcn/ui - Failed to load URL

Tags: reactjs, components, tailwind-css, styling

I'm trying to use shadcn for some styled components and having trouble importing one of their components. This is the error I am getting

```
Failed to load url /src/components/ui/input (resolved id: /src/components/ui/input) in /Users/dchoi/Github/bargain-battle/frontend/src/containers/Game/Game.tsx. Does the file exist?
```

In the network tab of my react application, I see that it's making a request to the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/components/ui/input?t=1687730147732
```

**/src/components/ui/input** in fact does not exist in my file structure. The Input component lives inside **/@/components/ui/input.tsx**.

Below is a picture of my file structure. How can I fix this error and properly import shadcn components?

[image]

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the import statement for the input component as:

```
import { Button } from './@/components/ui/button'
```

If the issue still persists, try to install and configure your shadcn project again.

During the installation and configuration of the project, You should add the code below to the **compilerOptions** of **tsconfig.json** file, so that the app can resolve any path without error.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"]
}
```

Also update **vite.config.ts** file with the code:

```
# (helps to import "path" without error)
npm i -D @types/node

import path from "path"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
})
```

Now when you set up shadcn-ui using the command :

```
npx shadcn-ui@latest init
```

and add any ui component like button:

```
npx shadcn-ui@latest add button
```

a reusable button component will be created at:
src/components/ui/button.tsx.

Now try to import it in your project as:

```
import { Button } from './components/ui/button'
```

This might solve your import issue.

Comment: This helped me. I did the init again. And I had to use a different path for the button import though. Actually I let the IDE auto-import the Button for me, & it was different now, not with @ anymore. Instead as such: `import {Button} from "../../../components/ui/button.tsx";`

Answer (score 0):

You can update the importing of cn in the input.tsx

from: import { cn } from "src/@/lib/utils"
to: import { cn } from "../../lib/utils"

I didn't follow the instruction regarding the tsconfig.json and vite.config.ts, because it affects the auto importing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).